# How to remove the tail from singly linked list in data structure

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

We cannot easily delete the last node of a singly linked list. Even
if we maintain a tail reference directly to the last node of the list, we must be able
to access the node before the last node in order to remove the last node. But we
cannot reach the node before the tail by following next links from the tail. The only
way to access this node is to start from the head of the list and search all the way
through the list. But such a sequence of link-hopping operations could take a long
time.

Comment: I think you may be trying to answer someone else's question rather than create your own, but, if not, yes you are absolutely correct. It would be much less time consuming with a doubly linked list with a previous node pointer.

Comment: In singly linked list data structure, to delete **any** node in the list you have to start traversing the list from the _head_ of the list and keep track of previous node of current node.

Answer (score 0):

It will at least take O(n) time complexity to delete the last node in singly linked list.

But, this can be done in O(constant), by using a doubly linked list.

Comment: I want to use singly-linked-list only

Answer (score 0):

Simply take a for loop that start from `i=0` upto `i<size` where `size` is the **number of nodes** in that singly linked list. The condition `next.getNext().getNext()==null` in the code below checks whether the node after the next node has reference `null` for **next node Reference** that is **tail** Then it simply sets `null` in next node reference.

See the method below.

```
public void removeLast() {
        Node<E> next=head;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            if(next.getNext().getNext()==null) {
                next.getNext().setNext(null);
                tail=next.getNext();
                size--;
            }
            next=next.getNext();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** `getNext()` returns reference of next node.

Since `getNext()` returns `Node` type reference so we can call `next.getNext().getNext()`

`size` keeps count of nodes create so far.

Comment: Your logic to remove last node will not work for the linked list with `1` node.

Comment: Yes for that we usually create remove head() function.     public E removeFirst() {
  if(isEmpty()) {
   return null;
  }
  E answer= head.getElement();
  head= head.getNext();
  size--;
  return answer;
 }

Comment: We can also add if(size==1){removeFirst();} in method described in answer.

Comment: _head_ node of the list is also a node of the list. Why to create a different function to remove it?

Comment: I am creating it because on removing `head` node we should assign `null` to the `head` because if we don't assign `null` to `head` then we will not be able to find starting point of linked list. Where head is a variable of class node

Comment: Creating `removeFirst()` can also make code reuse-able. Let us suppose we are creating following method `removeMiddle()` we should call `removeFirst()` if `size==1` . To ensure code reuseability we must create this method separately.

Comment: One function is enough for deleting any node from a singly linked list. You just need to keep the track of _previous_ node of the node to be delete. In case of _head_ node deletion there will be no previous node and the _head_ of node will be point to the _next_ node after deletion of first node of the list. That _next_ node will be `NULL` if the list is having only `1` node in it. Hence, the _head_ will end up pointing to `NULL` in this particular case. Do you still think there is a need of different function to remove the first node of the list?

Comment: For that kind of function we will be passing some parameter to the function. Yes we can create such a function which can delete any of the node. But for that we should pass some parameter that describes which number of node to be deleted. 1, 2, 3 or any other number. But we are required to remove last node.